# Disable Directory Listing in IIS

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, directory-listing

In my web application all the .aspx pages resides in Pages directory. The project structure is shown below:

[image]

The Home.aspx is set as Start Page and the Web.config file of the Pages folder contains:

```
<configuration>
<location path="Secured">
    <system.web>
    <authorization>     
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
</configuration>
```

And the main Web.config has:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Pages/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/Pages/Secured/Home.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

So when the application launches it redirects to the Login page with the URL:

> http://localhost:2453/Pages/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fPages%2fSecured%2fHome.aspx

Now if I delete the

> Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fPages%2fSecured%2fHome.aspx

from that URL and press enter it is taking me to the Directory Listing:

[image]

What I want that it will again send me to the Login page located at

> http://localhost:2453/Pages/Login.aspx

How can I achieve this? Your help be appreciated.

Thanks.

The localhost:
[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to disable directory browsing from IIS or from the web.config

```xml
<configuration>
  <location path="Secured">
    <system.webServer>
      <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

this entry above applies to IIS 7+, for IIS 6 you'll have to do it from IIS Manager

Comment: Thanks for reply. If I navigate to localhost as in the above image it is showing IIS7. But in Start->Control Panel->Administrative Tools I can see there are two Internet Information Services Managers. One is Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Managers and another Internet Information (IIS) Services Managers. I am unable to understand whether or not I am running in IIS7. Also I am executing the application from Visual Studio. I have tried your code both in main Web.config and in Web.config of Pages. But none of them is working. How can I disable it from IIS6 Manager?

Comment: @Tapas Bose currently your app is running on Asp.net development server (Cassini). You may have to configure it to run on IIS by going to the project properties > Web tab and setting it to IIS and creating a virtual directory

Comment: I have added your code in main Web.config and have changed the properties to use Local IIS server and now I am getting HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden error message if I try to browse http://localhost/EMSApplication.Web/Pages/. This will help to protect the website. But isn't there any way to redirect again in Login page? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TapasBose maybe you should put a default page on that folder (Default.aspx) a 403.14 means it can't load any default doc and from your screenshots i can see you don't have a default document.

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 ways using which you can disable the Directory Listing:
This has been tested & works for IIS 10.

### 1. Web.config

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <directoryBrowse enabled="false" /> <!--this line will disable directory browsing-->
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

### 2. IIS

Go to Internet Information Services(IIS) and look for the `Directory Browser` option. Select it and on the right corner you see an option `Open Feature`. Click on it and it will take you to another tab. Now select Disable and you see that the browsing has been disabled.

[image: IIS manager]
[image: IIS Directory Browsing]