# How do I restrict directory listings access in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, server

I've been having problems setting my 403 error page and I'm also having problems with restricting directory listings. How do I restrict directory listings? Is it done with IIS or can it be done in the asp.net program itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Directory Listing in IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806446/disable-directory-listing-in-iis)

Answer (score 0):

You can set it through IIS.

under IIS manager click on your respective website in left pane from Sites> Then In middle pane under IIS section click on Directory browsing & Disable it.