# IIS showing files in browser. How do I prevent this?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

My api is here: http://ip/myapi.svc.

If I call http://myip, the browser displays some files from the server.

[image]

What can I do to prevent this?

I'm using IIS 8.5 running on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your **WCF Service**. Your current **IIS Configurations** allows **Directory Listing.**

To disable it you can use the **IIS Manager** and then choose whether you want to disable it on site level or machine level.

After you've chosen the website or the the Server Choose **(Directory Browsing)** and on the right pane click **disable**.

Edit:

You can also disable directory listing from Web.config as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806446/disable-directory-listing-in-iis)

but I'm not sure if it will work with IIS 6