# Users see all file in wwwroot folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have problem about `wwwroot` in MVC4.
When I enter folder that is in `wwwroot` folder, all files are visible.
I don't want Users to see all the files in folder, But files are accessible in single request like:

```
mysite.com/folder/test.jpg
```

I don't have any idea.

Comment: This seems more a system admin problem than a programming one. See here: https://serverfault.com/questions/887113/how-do-you-stop-users-directly-accessing-files-on-a-website-in-iis

Comment: what do you mean by line But file accessible in **single request**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you mean you want to [disable directory browsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9806524/16563198)?

Comment: Also maybe you have configured to serve static files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0